# Gatsby <Link> or @reach-router <Link> between static page routes and client-only routes?

Tags: gatsby, reach-router

I've read the documentation Gatsby `<Link>`, client-only routes, and @reach/router.

I think I have a good understanding of how it works. However, I'm wondering whether there are recommendations for linking between static pages and client-only routes, in particular using Gatsby `<Link>` vs @reach/router `<Link>`

Let's say for example, that there are static pages at `/documentation/*`
And let's say there's an app with client-only routes at `/app/*`

There are 4 scenarios here:

1. static to static
   (e.g. a link on `/documentation/feature-1` to `/documentation/feature-2`):
   obviously should use Gatsby `<Link>` here.
2. static to client-only
   (e.g. a link on `/documentation/feature-1` to `/app/feature-1`):
   Should I use Gatsby `<Link>` or @reach/router `<Link>`? Does it matter? Since the destination is client-only, I'm guessing that pre-load for Gatsby `<Link>` won't work?
3. client-only to client-only
   (e.g. a link on `/app/feature-1` to `/app/feature-2`):
   I think I should use @reach/router `<Link>` for this. But could I use Gatsby `<Link>` here? Are there any benefits to doing so?
4. client-only to static
   (e.g. a link on `/app/feature-1` to `/documentation/feature-1`):
   In this case, I think should I use Gatsby `<Link>` since the destination is static and prefetching can happen.

Maybe the answer here is simple and I should just use Gatsby `<Link>` for everything, but I'm not sure if that's the right answer and what the implications are if any.

Thanks!

Comment: I've got exactly the same questions ... also waiting for any help here. Thanks for asking

Comment: I noticed that reach Link component will auto populate the URL depending on the router component that it originated from, so I had to use reach-router for this, else I would need to manually add the full link if using the gatsby Link component. I use gatsby link if the page destination is using the default gatsby routing configuration. I don't know if I'm missing out on anything special if I use reach Link vs gatsby Link other than this. Hopefully I'm doing it right!

Comment: On 2. my experience is that @reach/router Link doesn't work - gives a 404 page.  Gatsby Link seems to work fine.  For simplicity, I'm using Gatsby Link everywhere, and have not yet seen any negative side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
My article on medium to explain [here](https://medium.com/@shinabr2/comprehensive-guide-about-gatsby-routing-you-should-know-3bece0d3718).

For short, the `gatsby Link` component is a wrapper of `@reach router link` with added more useful stuff from `gatsby`, notable is `prefetch`, document [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/).

That's why if you need above gatsby stuffs, use `gatsby Link`. Otherwise, just go with `@reach router link`. For me, go all with `gatsby Link`.
Hope this helps. Please correct if I am going wrong.